# Can we install any assembler in Ubuntu

Tags: installation, programming, dosbox

I have got to practice the assembly language, for that i need an assembler. I installed **masm** (Microsoft-macro-assembler) over **DOSBOX** emulator, but it does not give me the code-view of my program. Is there any other assembler that could solve my problem?

Comment: The question is not clear to me. Can you please upload a screenshot of your currently installed assembler+view and edit your question, in order to add more information about this problem in particular. You can  of course install any program which is compatible with your OS and customize it to your needs. Look for "Preferences" within your program to customize it!

Answer (score 1):

From the software center you can install `yasm`, `nasm` or `binutils` (the assembler is actually called `as`) packages, all providing popular assemblers. To disassemble, you can use at least `objdump -d binary` or `gdb binary` to also run, trace, or modify it on the fly. Gdb has a learning curve, so you could try `ddd` as a frontend. Good luck practicing!

Answer (score 0):

Code View in the sense , you mean the source code ? in such case use 
c/>edit progname.asm

or try using this Dos Box emulator,i used this for my lab programs and it works fine, "http://ehowplus.com/how-to/install-masm-dosbox-linux-ubuntu/"

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.