# Assembler similar to TASM on Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, software-installation, 64-bit, intel, programming

I have an HP computer running 64-bit Ubuntu, so you could say Intel. I'm taking a assembly course at the university. The instructor wants us to use [TASM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_Assembler).

While it may run on wine I'm not sure about it. TASM is no longer maintained.

I have never written any assembly programs, but I would like to know if there's a assembler that runs natively on Ubuntu 64-bit, is free, is maintained and as close as possible to the TASM syntax as possible so I can follow the instructor without having to much trouble.

I have found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110176/can-we-install-any-assembler-in-ubuntu), however the answers given there don't say which one has the closest syntax to TASM, which is the main point of my question. I can find easily many assemblers with Google. I want to know which one has the closest syntax to TASM.

Comment: at the bottom of that very same wiki page there is a list of valid asm compilers, most of them are available for linux too .

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could install the Netwide Assembler, **NASM**:

```
sudo apt-get install nasm
```

NASM provides the `-t` option which enables the **TASM** Compatibility Mode:

> NASM includes a limited form of compatibility with Borland's TASM.
>   When NASM's `-t` option is used, the following changes are made:
>
> - local labels may be prefixed with @@ instead of .
> - size override is supported within brackets. In TASM compatible mode, a size override inside square brackets changes the size of the
>     operand, and not the address type of the operand as it does in NASM
>     syntax. E.g. `mov eax,[DWORD val]` is valid syntax in TASM compatibility
>     mode. Note that you lose the ability to override the default address
>     type for the instruction.
> - unprefixed forms of some directives supported (`arg, elif, else, endif, if, ifdef, ifdifi, ifndef, include, local`)

Alternatively, you could also run the windows version with [DOSBox](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DOSBox).

Source:

- [NASM Manual - section-2.1.23](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.1.23)

Answer (score 1):

Use NetWide Assembler...To install it just type in the terminal

```
sudo apt-get install nasm
```

Or you can build it from source

[NASM 2.13.03](https://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/releasebuilds/2.13.03/)

Best of luck...

Comment: since the accepted answer already details how to install this program with APT, perhaps you could elaborate on *how* to build it from source and *why* someone may want to do that, because at the moment your answer is not adding any useful information alongside the existing one.